# How to send {{ }} from database to flask jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have a case to render a template from a SQL database to jinja2.

In table shop, I have a string value like that in column shop.sms_body of table shop!

```
{{ location.name }} kính chào quý khách! 
Đã {{ order.days }} ngày kể từ đơn hàng {{ order.order_name }}, chúng tôi rất mong ý kiến của quý khách để ngày càng phục vụ khách hàng tốt hơn. 
Mong quý khách liên hệ chúng tôi qua số phone {{ location.phone }}, hoặc ghé thăm website {{ location.address1 }}! 
Chúng tôi chân thành cám ơn
```

In jinja2, my code is, i render shop, and get sms body {{ shop.sms_body|safe }}

```
<a class="text-left"
                       href="sms:{{ order.canonicalForm }}&body={{ shop.sms_body|safe }}"><img
                            src="/static/img/sms_icon.png" width="30px"></a>
```

When I click "sms message" this is what I want: `{{ location.name }}..` etc have to render phone of location, but it still like image

[image: SMS message still remain {{}} tag]

Does anyone have a solution to this case?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Thanks!
I find out solution
In flask

```
sms_body = shop.sms_body
    print(sms_body)
    sms_body = Template(sms_body)
    list_sms_body = [sms_body.render(shop=shop, location=location, order=order) for order in orders]
    if orders == []:
        return redirect(url_for("remind.update_remind_customer", date=date))
    else:
        return render_template('/remind_customer.html', orders=orders, shop=shop, location=location, date=date,
                               next_date=next_date, pre_date=pre_date, list_sms_body=list_sms_body)
```

after that in html

```
{% if shop.use_remind_customers == True %}
            {% for index in range(orders|length) %}
                {% set order = orders[index] %}
                {% set sms_body = list_sms_body[index] %}
<a class="text-left"
                           href="sms:{{ order.canonicalForm }}&body={{ sms_body|safe }}"><img
                                src="/static/img/sms_icon.png" width="30px"></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [escaping](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#escaping) section of docs? You can use the `raw` block for this

Comment: In database i have string like that {{ location.phone }}, i want jijna2 understand it is {{ }} as a fuction of jijna2, not string? I try raw but it is not work? Thank you

Comment: You have a few options, 1 is to generate your jinja templates on the fly from the DB, or 2. to use some other tool to pull the data into the page for example with JavaScript then use something like mustache JS to do the rest of the rendering.

Comment: thank you, do you have example for option 1? 1 is to generate your jinja templates on the fly from the DB,